# Automating a PL/SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, scheduled-tasks

I have created below pl/sql procedure. I want to schedule it to execute it every day. I am using dbms.job to schedule it to run in a particular time daily. The procedure compiles successfully. But it does not execute automatically though I scheduled.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Schema.Payment_Updation_Process
AS
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line ('The payments updation process started at '|| rpad(' ',0,' ')||SYSDATE); 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table account_new_arr_1'
;
update tab_dld
set dr_date = sysdate
where table_name = 'account_new_arr_1'
and dr_date is null
;
commit
;
insert into tab_dld
values ('account_new_arr_1',sysdate,null,null,null,tab_dld_seq.nextval)
;
commit
;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table account_new_arr_1
tablespace TOOLS
storage (initial 1M next 1M)
as (
select t1.customer_segment,t2.account_num,t2.last_bill_seq,
round((t2.total_billed_tot - t2.total_paid_tot);1000,2) new_arr
from accountattributes t1, account t2
where t1.customer_segment in (''01'',''05'',''31'',''32'',''36'',''37'')
and t2.account_num = t1.account_num
and t2.invoicing_co_id = 1
and to_char(t2.last_bill_dtm,''YYYYMM'') > ''201204''
and t2.currency_code = ''LKR''
)'
;

update tab_dld
set en_date = sysdate,
cc = (select count(*)
from account_new_arr_1)
where table_name = 'account_new_arr_1'
and en_date is null
and dr_date is null
;
commit
;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create index i_account_new_arr_1
on account_new_arr_1(account_num)
tablespace TOOLS
storage (initial 1M next 1M)'
;
END;
/
```

This is the way that I am trying to schedule.

```
declare 
jid number;
begin
dbms_job.submit(
    JOB => jid,
    WHAT => 'Payment_Updation_Process;', 
    NEXT_DATE =>  to_timestamp_tz('09-JULY-21 08.28.00 Asia/Calcutta',
  'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS TZR'),
    INTERVAL  => 'sysdate +1');
end;
/
commit;
```

When check the status using '`select * from user_jobs;`' it shows failures. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Have you run the procedure interactively?  Does it throw an error?  If a `dbms_job` job fails, the stack trace will be written to the alert log.  What command is failing?

Comment: Procedure does not throw an error and it does not executed either.

Comment: My guess is that the `create table` step fails because the semicolon in the statement `round((t2.total_billed_tot - t2.total_paid_tot);1000,2) new_arr` doesn't make sense.  I'd assume you mean to divide or multiply by 1000.

Comment: If you execute a procedure interactively, it must either execute successfully or throw an error or run until you kill it.  Which of these three does your procedure do when you run it interactively?

Comment: What did you mean by interactively? I am sorry. I am new to this field.

Comment: Interactively means running the procedure at, say, a command-line while you wait for the response.

Comment: Why are you doing it? What's the point in dropping the table and then creating it (along with its index) **every day**? Create it **once**, use it every day, **truncate** its contents if you don't need it. I'd understand if it were something "dynamic", but there isn't, so I'd suggest you to think it over.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't use the standard scheduling package, dbms_scheduler? It's a lot more flexible than the ancient dbms_job and captures more details such as runtime errors.